# Can't get request headers values from Angular HTTP interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

In an Angular application, I use an interceptor to inject the token (when needed) into the request headers. I also need it to modify the `Content-Type` header to the appropriate one. By default, it must be `application/json`, but there is a call that needs to upload a ZIP file, so I want to let the `Content-Type` header as is (for these cases, it's something like: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvamnUWepE840OEuq`). I use this code:

```js
    intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let usr = this.userService.getActualUser();
        let confirmationToken = '';
        let credentials = false;
        let contentType = 'application/json';
        
        // Check if the incoming request has an specific content type header
        if (req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
          contentType = req.headers.get('Content-Type');
        }
    
        // ETC
    }
```

The problem is that `req.headers.has('Content-Type')` always returns `false`, so I'm setting the wrong type and the call fails. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the content of your form is an instance of the FormData object? If so,

```
if(req.body instanceof FormData)
```

This check might help you or give you some hints if you are unable to access the headers. Or maybe you could even dive deeper and check into the `req.body` object to do a check that is more specific.

Answer (score 1):

During your request, you would expect to see the `content-type` but you won't unless you directly specify this.

If you have this on your request, you will see the content type.

```
return this.http.get(this.ENDPOINT, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
})
```

This, however, could be an overkill.

Another possible solution is to check the instance type of the body and then set the headers accordingly

```
if (req.body instanceof FormData) {
    contentType = 'multipart/form-data';
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this solution but the call ends with an error stating `422 Unprocessable Entity`. I think it's because it expects the `boundary` value... Do you know how could I get this value? Thanks!

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction, the logic I needed was actually quite simple but I needed more coffee today to see it clear  :)

Comment: if my answer fulfills your original question, please vote up

Answer (score 1):

Following your advices, I came up with a very simple solution, that is leave the `Content-Type` header as is if the request body is form data, and set is as JSON for the rest. Something like:

```js
    if(!(req.body instanceof FormData)) {
      contentType = 'application/json';
    }
```

Cheers!